Values not appearing in ggplot plot
When I made a plot using geom_point() and geom_line(), a few values in the middle didn't appear and I can't figure out why.
I have a dataframe with 3 columns (K_value, CV_error, and Run), where K_value is categorical.
dput() output:
    structure(list(K_value = structure(c(10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"), class = "factor"), 
        CV_error = c(0.3496, 0.48953, 0.22838, 0.3241, 0.48187, 0.81215, 
        0.64932, 0.48208, 0.34502, 0.29175, 0.38106, 0.34349, 0.29372, 
        0.31848, 0.28904, 0.36266, 0.35706, 0.40682, 0.22942, 0.81252, 
        0.66357, 0.48312, 0.34643, 0.29845, 0.33101, 0.44156, 0.32816, 
        0.26834, 0.38874, 0.32601, 0.33054, 0.5124, 0.4978, 0.81195, 
        0.62714, 0.49569, 0.34549, 0.29434, 0.21027, 0.35551, 0.23482, 
        0.36595, 0.33906, 0.30915, 0.38615, 0.42463, 0.38548, 0.81222, 
        0.64116, 0.48115, 0.34543, 0.31653, 0.39421, 0.23617, 0.26476, 
        0.30773, 0.29044, 0.23667, 0.40504, 0.24453, 0.38279, 0.81107, 
        0.62831, 0.48073, 0.34307, 0.25076, 0.18189, 0.24538, 0.30349, 
        0.31099, 0.26404, 0.26664, 0.37712, 0.38249, 0.27946, 0.81362, 
        0.66236, 0.48343, 0.34475, 0.29682, 0.20412, 0.20799, 0.25753, 
        0.28842, 0.25157, 0.41521, 0.34065, 0.24796, 0.30641, 0.81291, 
        0.65986, 0.4821, 0.34447, 0.24829, 0.20115, 0.22076, 0.31345, 
        0.39544, 0.40846, 0.26986, 0.27907, 0.33826, 0.37872, 0.81762, 
        0.65032, 0.48309, 0.34895, 0.31037, 0.39639, 0.222, 0.33737, 
        0.23645, 0.35719, 0.42435, 0.2783, 0.41588, 0.43157, 0.81294, 
        0.6575, 0.47089, 0.34488, 0.24524, 0.29636, 0.22649, 0.23698, 
        0.30698, 0.40407, 0.3819, 0.31701, 0.47138, 0.34162, 0.81551, 
        0.66211, 0.49685, 0.34662, 0.23958, 0.32928, 0.19703, 0.25929, 
        0.29533), Run = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
        "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
        "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
        "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", 
        "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
        "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
        "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", 
        "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", 
        "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", 
        "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
        "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "10", "10", 
        "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
        "10", "10")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -140L
    ))

I wanted to plot the mean rate of change across K_value, like so:
df %>%
   mutate(rate = CV_error - lag(CV_error)) %>%
   mutate(sd = sd(rate),
     .by=K_value) %>%
   mutate(meanrate = mean(rate),
     .by=K_value) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x=K_value, y=meanrate)) + 
 geom_point() + 
 geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=meanrate-sd, ymax=meanrate+sd), width=0.2) + 
 geom_line(aes(group=1)) 

This yields:

Any idea why the data for K=10 is not appearing? The data for K=10 is there in the original df, and when I plot other things (e.g., the mean of CV_error) it shows up fine. I'm wondering if it has something to do with lag(). Am I using it incorrectly?

It's difficult to troubleshoot this if you don't provide the data !
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Are you sure there's no missing values in that row? Save your data after your mutates and look at it. If it all looks good to you, please run dput() on it to create copy/pasteable R code to reproduce the data and add it to your question so that it it reproducible.

Edited to include dput() output, apologies.

After I run your mutate lines and look at the data, all of the K_value = 10 rows have NA values. Your data show that K_value is a factor, and despite its levels being in the correct order your data is sorted alphabetically by K_value, not numerically, which mean "10" is the first row within each Run group, and when you lag the first value, you get a missing value....
df %>%
   mutate(rate = CV_error - lag(CV_error)) %>%
   mutate(sd = sd(rate),
     .by=K_value) %>%
   mutate(meanrate = mean(rate),
     .by=K_value) 

    K_value CV_error Run     rate          sd  meanrate
1        10  0.34960   1       NA          NA        NA
2        11  0.48953   1  0.13993 0.095314894  0.013977
3        12  0.22838   1 -0.26115 0.125867371 -0.018266
4        13  0.32410   1  0.09572 0.107924558  0.046913
5        14  0.48187   1  0.15777 0.110399314 -0.005331
6         1  0.81215   1  0.33028 0.085966983  0.441737
7         2  0.64932   1 -0.16283 0.013051558 -0.163086
8         3  0.48208   1 -0.16724 0.016702958 -0.166252
9         4  0.34502   1 -0.13706 0.007179984 -0.138402
10        5  0.29175   1 -0.05327 0.029021407 -0.066298
11        6  0.38106   1  0.08931 0.077438538  0.013361
12        7  0.34349   1 -0.03757 0.111384103 -0.022936
13        8  0.29372   1 -0.04977 0.082100970  0.013319
14        9  0.31848   1  0.02476 0.066958840  0.026454
15       10  0.28904   2 -0.02944          NA        NA
16       11  0.36266   2  0.07362 0.095314894  0.013977
...

If you sort your data correctly first, df |> arrange(Run, K_value) |> ... then you'll have K_value = 1 missing, not K_value = 10 (and correct values otherwise since the order is correct).
df %>%
  arrange(Run, K_value) |>
   mutate(rate = CV_error - lag(CV_error)) %>%
   mutate(sd = sd(rate),
     .by=K_value) %>%
   mutate(meanrate = mean(rate),
     .by=K_value) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x=K_value, y=meanrate)) + 
 geom_point() + 
 geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=meanrate-sd, ymax=meanrate+sd), width=0.2) + 
 geom_line(aes(group=1)) 


If you want values for K_value = 1, then you can set a default value in lag to fill in whatever you want for the first row within each group.

Thank you very much! It works exactly as intended now.
